Doubt in statement of Gauss' Lemma in Fulton's Algebraic Curves
In Fulton's Algebraic Curves (pg. 2), we are given the following definition of irreducible elements and statement of Gauss' Lemma:

An element $a$ in a ring $R$ is irreducible if it is not a unit or zero, and for any factorization $a = bc$, where $b,c \in R$, either $b$ or $c$ is a unit.

If $R$ is a UFD with quotient field $K$ , then (by Gauss) any irreducible element $F \in
R[X]$ remains irreducible when considered in $K[X]$.

But shouldn't $F$ be non-constant or else $F$ becomes a unit in $K$ (and hence in $K[X]$)?

Please search for answers before posting questions. Why do you doubt your counterexample? Please delete this duplicate question once all is clear.

Yes, we need $F$ to be a non-constant irreducible element. This is noted in Dummit and Foote's book just after the proof of Gauss Lemma. For example $2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$ but a unit in $\mathbb Q[X]$.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)
